# How to set edge of a graph with default value in a graph in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

How to set edge of a graph  with  default value in a graph in Networkx
I try this

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'weight', default = 1)
```

but seems not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html#networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes) for `set_edge_attributes` you will see the syntax is `(G, values, name)`, for the simplest form of the function which takes a scalar (1 in this case) and assigns it to the attribute `weight` for all of the edges:

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 1, 'weight')
```